# Dúvida sobre List que não retorna o resultado

Tags: java, lista

Tenho esse método em Java, que consulta no banco de dados e me retorna uma lista de alunos.

O método está consultando no BD, mas não retorna os dados corretamente...

```
public static List<alunos> teste() throws SQLException {

    String sql = "Select * from alunos";
    Statement stm = Conectar.Mysql(ip(), banco(), usuario(), senha(), sql);
    ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);
    List<alunos> valores = new ArrayList<>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        alunos objeto = new alunos();
        objeto.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
        objeto.setMatricula(rs.getString("matricula"));
        objeto.setCurso(rs.getString("curso"));
        valores.add(objeto);
    }

    return valores;
}
```

Ele me retorna `[teste.alunos@e26948, teste.alunos@1baeedf, teste.alunos@3f4d3d, teste.alunos@13b32d7]`

Comment: Por que não faz um laço para exibir cada item do ArrayList?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você deve sobrescrever o método [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) da classe `alunos`. Por exemplo:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return nome + " (" + matricula + ") - " + curso;
}
```

O método `toString` é o método responsável por dar uma representação em formato de `String` para algum objeto.

A implementação padrão que é herdada da classe `Object` não é lá muito útil, e é essa que você está obtendo, que retorna o nome da classe, seguido de um arroba e um código hash hexadecimal. Uma vez que a implementação padrão não deve servir, convém sobrescrevê-la com uma melhor.

Além disso, sugiro mudar o nome da classe para `Aluno` ao invés de `alunos`. O motivo disso é que o padrão para nomes de classes é usar substantivos no singular e começando com letra maiúscula.

Comment: Victor, muito obrigado resolveu o meu problema

Comment: @Junior Se a minha resposta te serviu, você poderia por favor marcá-la como aceita/correta ao clicar no símbolo ✅ verde aqui ao lado? Obrigado.

Answer (score 6):

Como o @VictorStafusa sugeriu, sobrescrever o método `toString()` é uma das formas, e além de outras ótimas observações a respeito do código apresentado.

Mas em relação a sobrescrita, eu particularmente não gosto de sobrescrever esse método, a não ser que seja por algo realmente justificável.

Se o método retorna um `ArrayList`, basta percorrer com um laço para exibir as informações:

```
ArrayList<alunos> listaAlunos = teste();

for(alunos a: listaAlunos){
   System.out.prinln("Nome: " + a.getNome() + 
     " - Matricula: " + a.getMatricula() + 
     " - Curso: " + a.getCurso());
}
```

Partindo do pressuposto de que, além dos setters, você também criou os getters para as propriedades da classe aluno.