# Dúvida sobre exercício com classe abstrata em Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, collection, classes-abstratas

Gostaria de pedir a ajuda de vocês novamente em mais esse exercício. Dessa vez usando a classe abstrata.

> Crie uma classe abstrata `FuncionarioAbstract` com o atributo `String` nome e o método abstrato: `public double getSalario();` Existem duas classes que herdam de `FuncionarioAbstract` e são concretas: `Administrador` e `Gerente`. `Administrador` possui um salário de 2000. `Gerente` já possui um atributo a mais `double comissao` e seu salário é `2500 + comissao`.
>
> Crie uma classe `Principal` com uma lista de `FuncionarioAbstract` (criando objetos do tipo `Administrador` e `Gerente`) utilizando a interface `Set` e a classe `HashSet` do pacote `java.util`. E crie um método `public static void imprimir(Set funcionarios)` imprimindo o nome e o salário de cada funcionário.

Já fiz as 3 classes e estou terminando a principal, vou postar o código aqui e gostaria de saber se está correto.

Classe `FuncionarioAbstract`:

```
public abstract class FuncionarioAbstract {
        
        private String nome;
        
        public abstract double getSalario();
    
        public String getNome() {
            return nome;
        }
    
        public void setNome(String nome) {
            this.nome = nome;
        }   
}
```

---

Classe `Administrador`:

```
public class Administrador extends FuncionarioAbstract {
        
        public double getSalario() {
            return 2000;
        }
    
}
```

---

Classe `Gerente`:

```
public class Gerente extends FuncionarioAbstract {
        
        public double getSalario() {
            return 2500 + comissao;
        }
        
        private double comissao;
        
        public double getComissao() {
            return comissao;
        }
        
        public void setComissao(double comissao) {
            this.comissao = comissao;
        }    
}
```

---

Classe `Principal`:

```
        public static void main (String[] args) {
    
    

            Set <FuncionarioAbstract> funcionario = new HashSet<FuncionarioAbstract>();

            Gerente funcionario1 = new Gerente();
            funcionario1.setNome("Ramon Oliveira");
            funcionario1.setComissao(1750);
            funcionario.add(funcionario1);

            Administrador funcionario2 = new Administrador();
            funcionario2.setNome("Eliana Franco");
            funcionario.add(funcionario2);
            
           
            
            imprimir(funcionario);

    }
    
    public static void imprimir(Set<FuncionarioAbstract> funcionario) {
        
        for (FuncionarioAbstract f : funcionario) {
            
            System.out.println("Nome do funcionário: " + f.getNome());
            System.out.println("Salário do Funcionário: " + f.getSalario());
        }
    }
    
}
```

A minha dúvida é seria como usar esse `Set` funcionários para imprimir o nome e o salário dos funcionários.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É só você iterar o `HashSet` e imprimir o que deseja

```
//Chamada do método
imprimir(fa);

//Declaração do método
public static void imprimir(Set<FuncionarioAbstract> funcionarios)
{
    for (FuncionarioAbstract f : funcionarios) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Nome funcionário %s", f.getNome()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Caso esteja utilizando **Java 8** você pode iterar da seguinte forma:

```
public void imprimir(Set<? extends FuncionarioAbstract> funcionarios) {
  funcionarios.forEach(this::imprimir);
}
```

E implementar o método que imprime individualmente:

```
private void imprimir(Funcionario funcionario) {
  NumberFormat formato = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

  System.out.println(funcionario.getNome() + " " + formato.format(funcionario.getSalario()));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Você pode sobrescrever o método `toString()` da classe `FuncionarioAbstract`. Veja um exemplo [nesta outra resposta minha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/165514/132). Ficaria assim:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getNome() + " - R$ " + getSalario();
}
```

Daí para fazer o método para imprimir, fica bem fácil:

```
public static void imprimir(Set<? extends FuncionarioAbstract> funcionarios) {
    for (FuncionarioAbstract func : funcionarios) {
        System.out.println(func);
    }
}
```

Você só precisa sobrescrever o método `getSalario()`. Ele é um método abstrato em `FuncionarioAbstract`. A classe `Gerente` o implementa de um jeito e a classe `Administrador` o implementa de outro.

Answer (score 2):

Reescrevendo o toString da classe FuncionarioAbstract, é só passar essa expressão lambda.

```
fa.forEach(n-> System.out.println(n));
```